# PowerShell: Download a List of Files from SMB Shares without Overwriting

Tags: powershell, smb

I'd like to download a list of pre-defined files from remote network shares, without overwriting local files that have the same name. I have this functionality mostly working in PowerShell through use of the Bitstransfer module. You can see in the code that C:\SMB\paths.txt points to a local file which includes remote SMB paths.

**SMBBulkDownload.ps1:**

```
Import-Module bitstransfer

foreach($line in Get-Content C:\SMBDump\paths.txt) {
    $sourcePath = $line
    $destPath = "C:\SMBDump\"
    Start-BitsTransfer -Source $sourcePath -Destination $destPath     
}
```

where **C:\SMB\paths.txt** contains (sample snippet):

```
\\10.17.202.21\some\dir\app.config
\\10.19.197.68\some\dir\app.config
\\10.28.100.34\some\dir\Web.config
```

The  code above downloads the files correctly **if** they have different file names. In the case where the file names are the same bitstransfer returns an ACCESSDENIED error. This could be due to the module not supporting same-name file copies, or due to race conditions in copying files with the same name at the same time. This is unfortunate because my work requires bulk downloads of many different files named the same, such as App.Config, Web.Config, etc.

**Error:**

```
Start-BitsTransfer : Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
```

Does anyone have a solution that can get around this same-name file copy block? I'd ideally like a solution that copies files with redundant names into the same directory with a "_1" or "_2" or _ suffix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your errors are rooted in your file names theory this would be something to try out.....

Your paths all have one unique component: the server IP address or name. I would suggest making a subdirectory for each address or append that to the name.

### Files organized in folders by host

```
foreach($line in Get-Content C:\SMBDump\paths.txt) {
    $hostName = ([uri]$line).Host
    $fileName = Split-Path $line -Leaf
    $destPath = "C:\SMBDump\$hostName\$fileName"
    Start-BitsTransfer -Source $sourcePath -Destination $destPath     
}
```

or

### Files in same folder with host naming prefix

```
foreach($line in Get-Content C:\SMBDump\paths.txt) {
    $hostName = ([uri]$line).Host
    $fileName = Split-Path $line -Leaf
    $destPath = "C:\SMBDump\$hostName-$fileName"
    Start-BitsTransfer -Source $sourcePath -Destination $destPath     
}
```

This should cause no name conflicts and as long as your file contains unique values there should be no contention here at all.

Comment: should that be `$destPath = "C:\SMBDump\$hostname\$fileName"` ? (Backslash between host and filename)

Comment: @NonSecwitter No. The second example is to have all files in the same directory. ex "10.17.202.21app.config". Although a small break in the name between the two would not hurt for readability.

Comment: Gotcha. Just a style difference, then. I'd also throw in a date if it's recurring: `$destPath = "C:\SMBDump\$hostname\$date\$fileName"` with `$date` being some formatted string like `YYYYMMDD`

Comment: That would be a good idea depending on the use case here yes. I'm sure the op would get the gist from this though.

Comment: Just tested this @matt. The second solution works like a charm! The first solution takes a filename (i.e. Web.config) and renames it to the hostname (i.e. 10.30.20.1), overwriting it whenever new Web.config files are discovered rather than creating unique directories. Regardless, your second solution is what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: Ah. I thought that if I gave it folder it would assume the rest. that does not appear to be the case. @Karimi I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Matt's approach is the way to go to keep unique file paths and allow you to trace files back to their source server.

To literally answer the question, you would need to check if the file you wish to copy exists, and change your path to avoid conflict.

```
Import-Module bitstransfer

foreach($line in Get-Content C:\SMBDump\paths.txt) {
    $sourcePath = $line
    $destPath = "C:\SMBDump\"      
    $fileName = Split-Path -Path $line -leaf

    if(Test-Path "$destPath$fileName"){
        $extension = [io.path]::GetExtension($fileName)
        $basename  = [io.path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($fileName)
        $i = 1

        do{
            $fileName  = "${basename}_$i$extension"
            if(-not (Test-Path "$destPath$fileName")){
                $next = $false
            }else{
                $next = $true
                $i++
            }

        }while($next -eq $true)

    }

    Start-BitsTransfer -Source $sourcePath -Destination "$destPath$fileName"    
}
```

Comment: `[io.path]::GetExtension()` and `[io.path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension()` would work wonders here. Also there is no need in this case for the curly braces with two variables are side by side in a string. `$this="this";$that="that";"$this$that"`. Your replace is potentially dangerous if the extension also appears in the name of the file.